# How to pass member values inside the union (which has nested structures)

Tags: c++

I have the union as followed in one of my project.

```
typedef struct  
{  
    teD eId;  
    union  
    {  
        struct  
        {  
            UCHAR ucVolume;  
        }stAng;  
        enum  
        {  
            TEMP_MP=0,  
            FD_MP,  
            FD_HP,  
            COHP,  
            PT_PARAM,  
            T_PARAM,  
            ME_TEST,  
            CK,  
            ER,  
            MIT,  
            FXSCR_IN,  
            F_OUT,  
            FEY,  
            FKEY,  
            FNT_HOLD,  
            FBSERT,  
            FOVE,  
            FBROR  
        }eud;  
        struct  
        {  
            UWORD ud;  
            enum  
            {  
                AR = 0,  
                ACE  
            }eAts;  
            enum  
            {  
                IM = -1,  
                ITY ,  
                PTY,  
                LOTY,  
            }eAe;  
            enum  
            {  
                APE = -1,  
                AHP,  
                AUP,  
                AP,  
                AMP,  
                AULMT,  
                ASERT,  
                AUE,  
                AOR  
            }eAude;  
            CHAR acPme[20];  
        }stAfo;  
    }una;  
}tssg;  

typedef struct  
{  
    teD eId;  
    union  
    {  
        char Data[1032];  
    } unMsgBuf;  
} tstMsg;  

const BOOL cMpssk :: mbPsg (const tstMsg  svd)  
{  
    tssg &tstAuMsg = (tssg&) svd;  
    case 1:  
    {  
        if(tstAuMsg.una.stAfo.eAts == ACE)
```

Here, I am setting `tstAuMsg.una.stAfo.eAts =1;` but still this if condition not getting through...

I don't understand clearly what could be the exact value should be passed to succeed the if condition.

This is little endian processor and considered 32-bit int.

Request your suggestions with some details why it's being failed that can shed some light on it.

Thank you,
Karthick

Comment: how did you assign the value to tstAuMsg.una.stAfo.eAts?

Comment: I suggest to print the value assigned and then check. printf("%d\n", (int) tstAuMsg.una.stAfo.eAts);

Comment: Actually, I am running the Vector cast for unit testing.  Where, since the structure becomes casts from one type to another tssg &tstAuMsg = (tssg&) svd;  Through user code, I assigned the values as;  const tstMsg  svd = {}; tssg &tstAuMsg = (tssg&) svd; tstAuMsg.una.stAfo.eAts =ACE;   this is how I assigned the value.  Once I executed the program, it never satisfy the if condition if(tstAuMsg.una.stAfo.eAts == ACE).  It looks like I am doing wrong with assigning the values to union members.